# Proving $\frac{dr}{dx_i}$=$\frac{x_i}{r}$ in Index Notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, solution-verification, index-notation

I'm self (re) learning index notation and some math for a fluid mechanics undergraduate lab research position, and am having trouble proving the following:

Given position vector **x** = <x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>>, and **r<sup>2</sup>** = x<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub>, how do I prove that $\frac{dr}{dx_i}$=$\frac{x_i}{r}$?

I'm also confused by what **r<sup>2</sup>** entails here physically; from the given definitions, wouldn't **r<sup>2</sup>** = |x<sub>i</sub>|<sup>2</sup>, and therefore **r** = **x** = x<sub>i</sub>e<sub>i</sub>?

Answer (score 1):

I think that with $r^2$ you mean $r^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$. Appart from that, the 0 gives you problems, but for any other point just calculate the classic derivative of $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$  with respect to the desired variable. You should get (for example) $\frac{dr}{dx_1}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}}2x_1=\frac{x_1}{r}$

Answer (score 1):

Physically, $r$ is the distance of the position vector $\mathbf x$ from the origin. That is, \begin{align*}
r &= \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^3} \\
\implies r^2 &= x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^3 \\
&= x_jx_j.
\end{align*}
Now, differentiating, \begin{align*}
2r \frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i} &= x_j \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i} x_j \\
&= 2 x_j \delta_{ij} \\
&= 2x_i.
\end{align*}
Thus simplifying, $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i} = \frac{x_i}{r}.$$